# Accessing webserver from public IP redirects to local IP of server and fails (ubuntu apache2, moodle hosting)

Tags: linux, webserver, apache2, moodle

I was able to setup a Moodle (learning platform) webserver via VirtualBox and Ubuntu desktop. On the local machine and LAN, Moodle can be brought up by visiting 192.xxx.xxx.xxx/moodle no problem. After opening port 80 on my network, I am also able to successfully bring up the Apache2 default index page by visiting my public IP address from an external network.

However, when I attempt to visit my.public.ip.address/moodle, Moodle redirects to the server's local 192.xxx.xxx.xx/moodle which obviously fails if visiting from an external network. How do I get Moodle to accept "my.public.ip.address/moodle" outright?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the public ip address for the www root?

In `config.php`

```
$CFG->wwwroot = 'http://my.public.ip.address/moodle';
```

Comment: I have done this and it actually solves the issue while creating another. Now i can access the moodle site from an external IP, but not from the localhost/moodle address. Nonetheless, this is a great improvement.